# React Native check if the route is not null

Tags: react-native

I am getting route from react-native in one component as below:

```
const { route } = this.props;
const { fromPage } = route.params;
```

But sometimes the route is null 9perhaps it was not set when navigating), how to check if that is null before getting the value like above?

Answer (score 1):

Should look at `useNavigationState`:

> useNavigationState is a hook which gives access to the navigation state of the navigator which contains the screen. It's useful in rare cases where you want to render something based on the navigation state.

[documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation-state/)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use a conditional statement, as I have shown below.

```
const { route } = this.props;
if (route && route.params) {
  const { fromPage } = route.params;
  // use `fromPage` here
} else {
  // handle the case where `route` or `route.params` is null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
const { fromPage } = this.route?.params || {}
```

`fromPage` param has type as `string | undefined`, you can check the condition of the param before using it